# ajax auto search and display dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to convert my dropdown to ajax auto search.

Here is my dropdown, when i select any company name it displays other 2 dropdowns by taking the id.

```
<select name="company" class="form-control" onChange="showSubcat(this);" required>
    <option value="">Select Company</option>
    <?php $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from company") or die (mysqli_error($con));
      while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $s2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $s2['company']; ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

In showSubcat(), i display 2 dropdowns from database.

As i have huge company names stored in database, its difficult to select from dropdown , so i want to convert this into ajax auto search. I tried to do like this

```
<input type="text" name="company" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off"  spellcheck="false" placeholder="Company Name">
```

Here i am facing 2 issues

1. This is taking company name , but i want to take company id so that
   i can display other 2 dropdowns
2. Not getting how to display 2 drop down based on this value, not getting how to call onChange()

Comment: you can using select2 http://select2.github.io

Comment: @HamedJavaheri: can u please provide me if any working examples other than this i can refer?

Comment: Try making your own research first, don't expect that someone is going to write for you a script from scratch, if you don't show some effort yourself.